# Uncaught ReferenceError: stageCounter is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

where it is used

```
$(function(){
        if($('.stage1_optiond').is(':checked')) {
            stage3d.show();
            var stageCounter = "stage_3d";
    };
});
```

where it is references

```
$(function() {

    stage3d_optiona.on('click', function(){
        continue3.css('opacity', '1');
          continue3.on('click', function(){
            if(stageCounter == "stage_3d") {
              stage4.show();
              stage3d.hide();
            };

          });
      });
});
```

Unfortunately, this error throws:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: stageCounter is not defined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you define the variable in one function and then try to reference it in another function directly? Of course this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing `.data()` , setting `stageCounter` at `this` : `document` `.data()`

```
$(function() {
  if ($('.stage1_optiond').is(':checked')) {
    stage3d.show();
    $(this).data().stageCounter = "stage_3d";
  };
});

$(function() {

  that = $(this);

  stage3d_optiona.on('click', function() {
    continue3.css('opacity', '1');
    continue3.on('click', function() {
      if (that.data().stageCounter == "stage_3d") {
        stage4.show();
        stage3d.hide();
      };

    });
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  if ($('input').is(':checked')) {
    //    stage3d.show();
    $(this).data().stageCounter = "stage_3d";
  };
});

$(function() {

  that = $(this);

  // stage3d_optiona.on('click', function(){
  //     continue3.css('opacity', '1');
  //       continue3.on('click', function(){
  if (that.data().stageCounter == "stage_3d") {
    // stage4.show();
    // stage3d.hide();
    alert(that.data().stageCounter)
  };

  //       });
  //    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="true">
```

Comment: @user3907211 `var stageCounter = "stage_3d";` was setting `stageCounter` local to first `.ready()` handler , not available at second `.ready()` handler as defined variable `stageCounter` . Setting `data().dataName` at `document` , allow accessing `data().dataName` at utilizing `$(element).data().dataName` or `$(element).data(dataName)`

Comment: thank you for the explanation. couldn't i justn't use $(this) directly rather than that

Comment: @user3907211 _"thank you for the explanation. couldn't i justn't use $(this) directly rather than that"_ Would appear to encounter same as original issue , i.e., different _scope_ , as `$(this)` would refer to `continue3` within `click` handler ?

Answer (score 1):

Your declaring one variable in one function then referencing the variable in another, this won't work due to variable scope.

I suggest you brush up on variable scope, in particular JavaScript variable scope as it's got different rules to most languages.

Comment: could I set and use global variables?

Comment: Yes that is one solution. Generally it is advised to only use global variables when absolutely necessary.